# RGui 3.0.1, tcltk, windows... R always on the top

Tags: windows, r

I wrote a R graphic program using RStudio. Graphics are from `tcltk` package. It works nice.

But when I try to source my R file in [RGui 3.0.1](http://www.r-project.org/), this ugly problem occurs :

- Every time I click on a tcltk button (of my tcltk window), R appears
- Everytime I resize/move my tcltk window, R appears
- every actions I do on my tcltk window brings R to the top.

Run this code :

```
library(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
```

and try to resize the generated window (using Windows default resizer button). You will see it.

I noticed that when R is reduced to task tray, all works the way I want.

Is there a way to keep my program to the top without this problem ?

I did the function bellow, I copied and pasted it along my code, and it seems to be good except the second point (Everytime I resize/move my tcltk window, R appears).

```
appear <- function(){
        tkwm.deiconify(myWin)
        tkfocus(myWin)
}
```

Is there a way to definitely arrange that problem ?